# Is it possible to hide help button from wizard page org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, wizard

I create a file creation page by extending class WizardNewFileCreationPage. What I am trying to do is to hide the help button on the left bottom corner. Any suggestions on how to do this? 
Thank you.

Comment: The bottom row of buttons belongs to the `Wizard` / `WizardDialog` not the page

Answer (score 0):

Call this method: `Wizard#setHelpAvailable(false)`
Refer [API here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/wizard/Wizard.html#setHelpAvailable(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

I called this method but not working. See the following:
public class NewTDLDiagram extends Wizard implements INewWizard {

```
private NewDiagramFilePage page;

public NewTDLDiagram() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setHelpAvailable(false);            
}
```

...
}

This class is registered as an extension point of org.eclipse.ui.newWizards:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
<wizard
        class="com.abc.graphicview.ui.NewDiagram"
        icon="icons/NewSmdWizard.gif"
        id="com.abc.graphicview.ui.diagrawizard"
        name="Diagram"
        project="false">
     <selection
           class="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
     </selection>
 </wizard>
</extension>
```